# Kivy - Making a button/thumbnail with URL image as background

Tags: android, python, ios, kivy

I have started working with Kivy recently and have encountered a problem. I need to make a button/thumbnail with a URL image as background. I got some help on the Kivy user forum [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/kivy-users/qbNh4XrEnqg) but am still a little stuck. Here is my code just for that part:

```
for image_set, image_type in zip(categorized_images, image_types):
    layout = GridLayout(cols=2, size_hint=(None, None))
    layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
    scroll_view = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(320, 200))
    section = AccordionItem(title='%s' % image_type)
    layout.add_widget(back_button1)

    for image_path in image_set:
        layout.add_widget(AsyncImage(source="http://www.example/"'%s' % image_path,\
                                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(160, 160)))

    scroll_view.add_widget(layout)
    section.add_widget(scroll_view)
    accordion.add_widget(section)
```

What I have now is just a bunch of images being created, but I need thumbnails to be created that will lead to the full sized images. Besides that I have the builder.load_string part and the ButtonBehavior class part mentioned in the Kivy link. I just don't know how to implement in that "for loop". Is it possible to treat the UrlBut instance as a widget?

Answer (score 0):

## Thumbnail to Full Image

Make UrlBut create and store a thumbnail when it is instantiated. You can do this with [`PIL`](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), follow this tutorial http://andrius.miasnikovas.lt/2010/04/creating-thumbnails-from-photos-with-python-pil/

Then, have the `on_press` method (or equivalent) create a pop-up or overlay that contains the full size image.

## Treating the UrlBut as a Widget

Read this: http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-template

The Kivy docs say that a template defined in the kv file may be instantiated within your Python code like this (I am adapting the example given at that link):

Your kv language template:

```
[UrlBut@ButtonBehavior+AsyncImage]:
    source: ctx.source
    button_grab: True
    on_press: eval(ctx.on_press)
```

Then in Python, you can instantiate the template with:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

urlbut1 = Builder.template('UrlBut',source='http://lorempixel.com/400/200')

# create a second template with a different image
urlbut2 = Builder.template('UrlBut', source='http://lorempixel.com/400/200')
# and use urlbut1 and urlbut2 as other widgets.
```

Then, you could automate this with a for-loop:

```
for image_path in image_set:
        layout.add_widget(Builder.template('UrlBut',source="http://www.example/"'%s' % image_path)
```